# Pyinstaller не могу собрать программу

Tags: python, pyinstaller, python-import, pynput

Есть рабочий код, который отслеживает нажатия клавиш с помощью библиотеки `pynput`.

```py
from pynput import keyboard


def on_press(key):
    print('press', key)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    t = keyboard.Listener(on_press=on_press).start()
    input('Press Enter to close program')
```

Если собрать его с помощью `pyinstaller` то при запуске появляется ошибка:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Windows 10, Python3.7.6, Pyinstaller 4.2

Как это можно исправить?

Comment: Укажите OS, версию Python, и версию PyInstaller.

Comment: @Александр Спасибо за замечание, добавил.Windows 10, Python3.7, Pyinstaller 4.2

Comment: Я могу предположить что модуль pynput, использует какую то DLL или PYD.

Comment: А PyInstaller не зашивает его в архив.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Эта проблема связана с *динамическим импортом*.

PyInstaller не знает что pynput собирается подгружать ещё что то.

Решение такое:

```
C:\cmd>pyinstaller your_script.py  --hidden-import "pynput.keyboard._win32" --hidden-import "pynput.mouse._win32"
```